# Seeking binary thresholding tool in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.6

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.

I want to perform OTSU thresholding.

Where is the binary thresholding tool in ArcGIS Desktop 10.6?

Comment: Where have you looked?  What makes you think that there will be one?  What is “OTSU”?

Comment: @PolyGeo I read this thing in the this article: A Comparison of Water Indices and Binary Thresholding Techniques for Water Surface Delineation for St. Croix Watershed Area. For the present study, Otsu thresholding was performed using the binary thresholding tool in ArcGIS 10.6.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: [First Google result for "ArcGIS Otsu"](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/binary-thresholding-function.htm)

Comment: @mikewatt I know this link already. My question is where is this function located inside the ArcGIS Desktop 10.6. I can't find it.

Comment: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/editing-functions-on-a-raster-dataset.htm

Comment: @mikewatt got it. Thanks

Comment: @studysmart do you have access to ArcGIS Pro? I can't remember if that comes with ArcGIS Desktop. If so, I can tell you how to do it with Pro. I just figured it out myself.